# EasyAdmin convert value

Tags: php, symfony, entity, easyadmin

For work I need to read through Symfony 5: The Fast Track. But in chapter 9 I have some problems. I have two entities Conference and Comment. The Comment entity is connected with the ID of the Conference.
Comment:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Conference::class, inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $conference;

public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
{
    $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

public function getConference(): ?Conference
{
    return $this->conference;
}
```

My EasyAdminController looks like this:

```
public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
{
    return [
        MenuItem::linkToCrud('Conference', '', Conference::class),
        MenuItem::linkToCrud('Comment', '', Comment::class)>setController(CommentCrudController::class),
    ];
}
```

And the CommentCrudController likt that:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('author'),
            TextEditorField::new('text'),
            TextField::new('email'),
            DateTimeField::new('createdAt'),
            IdField::new('conference')->formatValue(function ($value) {
                dd($value);
            }),
            TextField::new('photoFilename'),
        ];
    }
```

So first my problem is that I need values as a object of Conference. Because I don't know how to do it right I tried to use formatValue but the `dd($value)`is never executed.

Can someone help me with that problem or link me somewhere where I can find the answer?

Comment: I think you're mistaken ``IdField`` with ``AssociationField``.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed :)